# What is the difference between a portmanteau and a kenning?

Tags: meaning, compound-words, portmanteau-words

Their definitions seem to blur for me, as well as compound words in general. I'm thinking it might be a "square is a rectangle but a rectangle is not a square" concept but I'm not certain.

Examples are also greatly appreciated.

Comment: Please add suitable dictionary/encyclopedia definitions, linked and attributed, or your question may be closed for lack of signs of reasonable research.

Comment: Kennings occur in Old English. Portmanteaux are combinations where you can see the meaning of both parts; the name doesn't help, since _portmanteau_ used to refer to a kind of bag into which one can stuff anything. Just call them all "noun compounds" if there's a space involved, or "compound nouns" if there's no space between the parts. That covers everything, and explains nothing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The words *portmanteau* and *kenning* come from different contexts and refer to different kinds of compounding. *Kenning* was first used in English by 19th century scholars trying to describe a feature of Old Norse and Old English poems: the use of periphrastic compound expressions instead of a simple description of a thing ([OED](https://oed.com/view/Entry/102922)). Here are a few examples that show the compounding at work ([Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_kennings)):

- sea => *hron-rad* (whale road)
- honor => *weorðmyndum* (worth of mind)
- sun => *heofen-candel* (heaven-candle)

Kennings often involve some kind of creative analogy, like imagining a sea as a road for whales, or the sun as a candle in the sky. Introductory literature courses often introduce *kennings* as a feature of Old English; if someone is talking about English in general, they are more likely to talk about a *compound* of some kind, like the noun compound "seat belt".

*Portmanteau* in English has referred to a specific kind of bag since the 16th century ([OED](https://oed.com/view/Entry/148217)). In the 19th century, Lewis Carroll adapted the term to refer to a word blending representative sounds from two or more words ([CJR](https://www.cjr.org/language_corner/chortle.php)):

> Well, 'SLITHY' means 'lithe and slimy. ' 'Lithe' is the same as 'active. ' You see it's like a *portmanteau* — there are two meanings packed up into one word.

So portmanteau don't just put two words together into a compound, but delete parts of the word to more fully blend them. So it's not *smoke-fog* but *smog*; it's not *brother-romance* but *bromance*.